# Magento Mass Import images with MAGMI - images excluded

Tags: mysql, magento, magmi

thanks for reading.

I'm using magmi to import more than 30.000 products with images.

The problem is with images that they are imported but all of them are excluded.

Is there any sql query that I can use and get all images included?

I used this query but only one row effected

```
update `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` set disabled=1 where `value_id` in (select `value_id` from `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` where value in (select value from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where `attribute_id`=(select `attribute_id` from `eav_attribute` where attribute_code='image' and `entity_type_id`=4)));
```

can you please help me? thank you.

magento 1.8 CE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as said in [plugin documentation](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor#Explicit_.E2.80.9Cexclude.E2.80.9D_flag_management.) , just put a "+" sign before the image name to import.

The reason "exclude" is checked is that default magento behaviour for base images is to avoid replicating them in the "extra" images gallery.

However, some extensions require to have base image displayed in the extra image list.

Btw, i would also advise using the [latest git version of magmi](http://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git) , which is much more up to date and has several enhancements

Comment: Documentation doesn't work any more. Is there an alternate link to read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to force images to be shown then an alternative (apart from the unadvised hacking Magento core) is to hack Magmi import

In Magmi 0.7.21

magmi/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/imageprocessor/imageitattributeemprocessor.php

line 155, in the function getExclude

change the return line to 0
`return 0;`

this will make every image show on product pages (after update or reimport of course).