# Mass Importing Images Magmi

Tags: image, magento, import, magmi

How would I mass upload products with images all at once. Say I have 1000 products with images can I upload all in one step and how? Instead of individually uploading one product and image at a time.

Comment: take a look at this - http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22443072%2Fmagento-mass-import-images-with-magmi-images-excluded&ei=jmi9VLOQD4y1ggTDrYTwCQ&usg=AFQjCNHqxaDB5Ye8Eul7r7oNfIESoYTPFA&sig2=80clsM_p4_OYHv4MuKdkWg&bvm=bv.83829542,d.eXY

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Mass Import images with MAGMI - images excluded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443072/magento-mass-import-images-with-magmi-images-excluded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magmi only updates the database, and since images are not stored in the database, you can not upload the actual image files using Magmi. You need to first upload all of the images onto your server using FTP, then you can use Magmi to map each product to its appropriate image.

So if you have products with skus 001, 002, and 003. And images with file names 001.jpg, 002.jpg, and 003.jpg. You first upload the images to the server, then make your CSV look like the following in order to map the images to the correct products.

```
sku,image,thumbnail,small_image
001,001.jpg,001.jpg,001.jpg
002,002.jpg,002.jpg,002.jpg
003,003.jpg,003.jpg,003.jpg
```

Also make sure that you upload the images to the correct directory which is matched in the Magmi "image attribute processor" plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with Magmi. Configure your Image Attribute Processor like the following image.

[image]

Next, upload all your images to `/Magento Root/media/import/`.

Finally, update your CSV to include the image name for the following fields.
`image, small_image, thumbnail`. Example: `image.jpg`

You can also add the label for these as well.
`image_label, small_image_label, thumbnail_label`